# How do I check which template is being used in Marionette ItemView

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I have multiple templates declared in my Marionette ItemView and when I render my ItemView I say which template I want to use.

```
templates: {
    'images': ImageResultTmpl,
    'music': MediaResultTmpl,
    'videos': MediaResultTmpl
},
```

Inside a method in the ItemView can get the name of the active template?

```
if(music){
    do this;
}
else{
    do that;
}
```

Comment: how do you determine which template to use when you render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is that you should just have different ItemViews for each template and render the correct ItemView depending on the situation. If you're trying to DRY up your code, maybe create a base ItemView that holds the common code and then have specialized ItemViews that extend that base class.

Comment: Thank you, but I am editing other's code and they are dicks about changing the structures.